# Помогите разобраться с дефолтным и собственным профилем spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, jar, spring-boot

В проекте использую технологии **Spring boot**, **Spring security**, **Hibernate**, внутрь `jar` добавляю **tomcat**. В `idea` все работает, но при запуске `jar` файла выдает ошибку. Ссылается на профиль `spring boot`. Как с ним работать? Или возможно ошибка в другом?

> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$Data
>   SourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for
>    database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one
>    on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular
>   profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).

`application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/game_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

`config.properties`

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

`pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
  <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Вот это ошибкааа)))) Ну короче да, по одиночке читаешь Stacktrace и узнаешь где там ошибка))) только вот ищи нужный трейс сам :DD

Comment: `Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If y ou have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active)`

Comment: перевод: Не удалось определить вложенный класс драйвера базы данных, тип базы данных `NONE`. Если вы хотите встроить базу данных то подключите поддерживаемый в `classpath`.  Если вы уже имеете параметры базы данных, которые будут загружены из определенного профиля, вы должны активировать его (На данный момент нет активных профилей)

Comment: у меня для подключения к бд используются application.properties и config.properties. В jar они есть. Что подразумевается под активировать профиль?

Comment: не совсем понятно, в мавен, у вас прописан драйвер для hsqldb базы данных, а в конфиге путь до  mysql.  И почему там кстати скоуп runtime?

Answer (score 0):

нету подключения к СУБД, в idea драйвер был подключен а в .jar его нету, надо в билд добавить драйвер.

Comment: Я добавил к артефакту драйвер jdbc но результата нет

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте mysql драйвер в зависимости:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.13</version>
</dependency>
```